# What should I expect to pay for pin lock Corny Kegs?

Tags: kegging, keg, corny-keg

It seems like corny keg prices are all oer the map.
doing a simple search for "used pin lock cornelius keg" I see them from $11.99 on ebay to $38.95 on Cornykeg.com

That's a huge swing.

Relatively speaking, $40 isn't a ton of cash for something that has a lot of parts and steel, (considering a glass carboy goes for about the same or more), but if I can get 3 or 4 for the price of one, and they're the same quality?

I bought a kit from my LHBS 2 kegs, CO2 tank, regulator, hoses and picnic faucet... and nw I want to have 1 or 2 kegs on deck because of the inevitible.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current going prices for reconditioned kegs are closer to $60-70/ea on other sites, a bit less if you're willing to put up with cut handles or other minor deficiencies. $40/keg is a good deal. $12/keg is too good to be true. :)

Comment: I had a feeling about the too good to be true part, but didnt realize that 40 was such a great deal. 
Thanks!

Comment: Also, make sure a reconditioned keg has been pressure tested. Cheaper kegs might have skipped this making them unsafe and you'll find yourself spending more money on replacement costs and brewing new batches that will be ruined form oxidation.